# Loading FLOAT values to table using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a table with column values like `12.1, 12.8, 34.2` in this format. When importing these values into another table using SSIS, the values loaded into the destination table are being rounded down, like `12.0, 13.0, 34.0`. How can I ensure the same values get loaded into the destination table as existed in the source table?

Comment: ROUND(), and cast?

Comment: Hey, I want to get the output as same as input. But it is rounding off in Destination table. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see the schema (specifically column types) for the source and destination tables - are both fields of type `FLOAT`?

Comment: My Source Field - convert(decimal(10,1),DATEDIFF(DAY, b.VALIDFROM,getdate())/365.25)  and Destination table data type is [ServiceDuration] (decimal(10,1) NULL. I have tried converting the Data concersion to DT_R4 in SSIS Package also. Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of that column in the Output of your Source component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DT\_Decimal Data Type Cutting off Decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518534/dt-decimal-data-type-cutting-off-decimal)